# AutoLayout. Stick UITableView to the bottom of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I need to achieve layout shown below. There are `UIView` and `UITableView` inside `UIScrollView`:

1. `UITableView` should be aligned right at the bottom of `UIScrollView`
2. `UITableView` should not have scrolling, so it's height should be adjusted according to content.
3. Row count is not static value.

[image: Scheme]

Here are the constraints of `UITableVIew`:

[image: UITableView constraints]

If I understand AutoLayout correctly, everything should be fine, but as result I get `UITableView`'s height to be 0. What's wrong with this setup?

Comment: Why do you want a non-scrolling table view inside a roll view? How will that be different than just a scrolling table view? BTW, there's no such thing as a UIContainerView.

Comment: waht exactly are you trying to achieve with that setup? I don't know what you are displaying above the UITableView but the normal setup for this setting would be to use a UITableView (It is a Subview of UIScrollview) and add the things that you want to display above it as a tableHeaderView to your tableView

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks, edited my question. `UIView` is a container for external ViewController, so I can't put inside first row in `UITableView`, so i decided to separate it from table.

Comment: @Amandir Thanks! I forgot about header view. Can you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are displaying above the UITableView but the normal setup for displaying something, that is above the tableView and scrolls with the tableview would be to use a UITableView (It is a Subview of UIScrollview and thus handles the scrolling itself) and add the things that you want to display above it as a tableHeaderView to your tableView.